java process keep re-starting after kill it with command: kill -9 pid
I have a screen called bung were inside i run a java process using ./start.sh (script to run the java process) but before type that command i start the screen running screen -r bung so i open the process and leave the screen with ctrl+a+d
in some time the process freezed so i join on screen ctrl+c it and stop it. but when i try open it, it says is already oppened. so when i type the command bellow it says is java process running, if i try to kill it, it get killed, but re-execute the script oppening the java process again, and i cant solve that issue, cause its keep restarting.
[root@vmi1478348 ~]# pgrep -a java
24979 java --illegal-access=permit -Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=4 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=https://mcflags.emc.gs/ -Daikars.new.flags=true -jar bung.jar nogui

[root@vmi1478348 ~]#
maybe there is a ghost screen were it still running ?
[root@vmi1478348 ~]# screen -ls
There are screens on:
        18043.lob       (Detached)
        10196.fac       (Detached)
        10100.hu3       (Detached)
        9868.bung       (Detached)
4 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.

[root@vmi1478348 ~]#


solution : should to kill another process pid
root     22592  0.0  0.0 113292  1476 pts/1    S+   03:28   0:02 /bin/sh ./start.sh
that process pid was restarting the java process pid
